# Poisson equation of a point charge in spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, voltage, conductors, boundary-conditions

I have to find the potential between two concentric grounded conducting spheres with a point charge betweem them. Gounded means that the boundary conditions are $\phi (r=a)=\phi (r=b)=0 $.

I understand that I have to find $\phi (r,\theta)$ from $\Delta \phi =\frac{q\delta ^{3}(r)}{\epsilon _0}$ where r is the position of the point charge. Also if we put the center of the spheres at the origin and the charge in the z-axis, we have azimuthal symmetry. I think that it is possible to use the general solution for the Laplace equation with azimuthal symmetry, find a particular solution for the Poisson equation and then apply the boundary conditions, but I don't have an idea how to find the particular solution.

Note: Sorry if I wrote something wrong (the equations or my grammar).